# Cyclic inequality with $a+b+c=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, buffalo-way

> Let $a;b;c$ be positive real numbers such that $a+b+c=1$
> Prove: $$a^2+b^2+c^2+a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+4abc \geq \dfrac{16}{27}$$

---

First, I tried with $abc \geq (a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)$
But it gave nothing.

Then I tried to add: $a^2b+\dfrac{b}{9}+b^2c+\dfrac{c}{9}+c^2a+\dfrac{a}{9}-\dfrac{1}{9}$

Then AM-GM, but from it, I got: $\dfrac{2}{3}(a^2+b^2+c^2)+4abc \geq \dfrac{10}{27}$

I think it's wrong, I'm stuck here.
Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: If you are familiar with calculus, you can use lagrange multipliers for this question

Comment: Thanks Calvin, edited, my mistake.

Comment: person: thank you, but I'm just a high school student, so I've not learned about calculus

Comment: Although I am a bit unfamiliar with this, the Purkiss principle may yield useful results

Comment: @Nguyenthuyhangaz proof  completed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim**:$$27(a^2c+b^2a+c^2b+abc)\le 4{(a+b+c)}^3$$
**Proof**:WLOG $a=\min(a,b,c)$ then take $b=a+u,c=a+w$ where $u,w\ge 0$ then we have to prove $$-9au^2+9auw-9aw^2-4u^2+15u^2w-12uw^2-4w^3\le 0$$ $$-9a(u^2-uw+w^2)-{(u-2w)}^2(4u+w)\le 0$$ which is true

---

thus $$a^2c+b^2a+c^2b+abc\le \frac{4}{27}\tag 1$$

we have to prove  $$a^2+b^2+c^2+4abc+a^2b+b^2c+c^2a\ge \frac{16}{27}$$ using (1) it suffices to prove:$$a^2+b^2+c^2+ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ac(a+c)+5abc\ge \frac{16}{27}+\frac{4}{27}$$ using $a+b+c=1$ and some mainipulation we have to prove $$ab+bc+ca-2abc\le \frac{7}{27}$$ WLOG $c=\min(a,b,c)$ then $c\le 1/3$ or $1-2c>0$ $$ab+bc+ca-2abc-\frac{7}{27}=\color{red}{ab}(1-2c)+c(1-c)-\frac{7}{27}$$ $$\le \color{red}{\frac{{(a+b)}^2}{4}}(1-2c)+c(1-c)-\frac{7}{27}\tag{AM-GM}$$ $$=\frac{{(1-c)}^2}{4}(1-2c)+c(1-c)-\frac{7}{27}$$ $$={(3c-1)}^2(6c+1)\frac{-1}{108}\le 0$$ which is true and proof is completed(phew!)

**Acknowledgement**:Earlier I only had a partial proof (I could prove only  LHS$>15/27$) ,But tbanks to [River-Li](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/584414/river-li) who proposed a stronger Claim(see comments)  and made some corrections the proof is done!

Comment: obligatory, there's a typo between (1) and (2), I believe it's "from" not "form"

Comment: Nice trick. (+1). You may use $a^2c+b^2a+c^2b + abc \le \frac{4}{27}{(a+b+c)}^3=\frac{4}{27}$ to prove the original inequality.

Comment: @RiverLi done!!

Comment: It is nice. In your last equations, you actually assume $1 - 2c \ge 0$ (red text) which is true if you assume $c = \min(a,b,c)$. $a^2c+b^2a+c^2b + abc \le \frac{4}{27}{(a+b+c)}^3$ is quite known (e.g. in the link you gave in earlier version).

Comment: @RiverLi fixed!!  thank you for your support and time :)

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore You are welcome.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are my hero <3

Comment: @Nguyenthuyhangaz glad to have helped,thank also RiverLi without whom the proof would be incomplete